# Bluetooth headset doesn't work as headphones only as hands-free (headset) on windows 11

Tags: windows, bluetooth, windows-11

I've just upgraded on Win11. And now, I'm having some troubles with my bluetooth...
My old headphones worked properly on window10 before upgrade.
Now, after connecting them to the notebook, I have the folowing situation:

1. [connection is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLK1J.png) but my Headphones has only "Voice" label, doesn.t have any "Music". The same view in a Music devices window - only Voice hands-free device.
2. if I switch of my Headphones (or disconnect bluetooth), a Headphones device appears in Devices section [Devices section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3p51.png)

Can anybody give me an idea, what's going on? It's a bug, or a feature of Win11?

P.S. I have already updated, all drivers: bluetooth, audio, everrything I could found usefull. I've alredy deleted device from device manager, installed them again, updated drivers and so on...
Thanks a lot, for any idea!

Comment: I have a similar issue. I found out that once I disallowed access to my Headset in the "Input Devices" section it switches correctly to the Headphone Profile (you might have to once change the volume to create a new sound). For me only a very bad work around since I actually use it for calls as well.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Bluetooth settings in Device manager and disable the AVRCP driver for you headphones. This will force the audio out to the Headset( the one with a microphone).

You will not have a selection for default audio out in Windows 11 Setting. but if you click the arrow next to the volume control on your task bar you can select the headset HD.

Comment: Thanks. this resolves my Aftershokz Opemcomm problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if your headset isn't connecting to for example both your phone and your laptop at the same time.

Another thing worth checking is if it shows up in microphone settings. Windows' it's implementation for Bluetooth audio is a bit funky as it supports the following:

- Headsetname (stereo) - Which is output only, high quality audio
- Headsetname (Hands-free) - Which is output and input, has low quality audio

If the 2nd one, the hands-free mode is selected for your Input device (microphone), I believe you're note able to select the music / stereo mode. So perhaps try changing your microphone and see if the other option unlocks.

Note that this is going off my experience with Windows 7/10, I've not really used 11 but hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I checked the connection to other device - no other connection, I'm sure it's not that case.

Comment: In a perfect situation the one headset must appear in a Sound panel:
in a Play tab: (1) stereo headset, (2) hands-free
and in a Mic (record) tab: (3) only hands-free. 
IMPORTANT: if I force delete the device "hands-free" from the Sound panel Record tab. And after reconnecting bluetooth I get the only one device - Headset (stereo) in Play tab with a correct sound in ears...

Answer (score 1):

This work for me with my Bose QC ear buds.
What I believe is happening is that windows 10 would show 2 types of blue tooth options (hands free and stereo) and windows 11 only shows 1. However, windows 11 does show hands free and stereo options in the Sound, video and game controllers.

So my solution was this:

1. Open device manager
2. scroll down and open "Sound, video and game controllers"
3. Right click on the hands-free option and select disable
4. Restart your computer

Now your audio has no option other then to play sound with your stereo and not your hands-free audio.

Comment: Doesn't this prevent you from using the microphone?

Answer (score 0):

This case fixed for me by selecting another input device from `Sound settings`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. So I started looking at the settings.
For me, I had my Bluetooth headphones (Sony WH-XB910N) disabled in the sound settings. Enabling it solved my problem.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0pwc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had a really similiar issue: headphones connecting only with microphone and when choosing as headphones - poor quality and only hands free version.
**Fixed by disabling *Intel Smart Sound Tech for Bluetooth* in Drivers tab in Device manager and restarting my laptop.**

Answer (score -1):

Im also having the same problem with no luck. Just can't connected to stereo mode even after disabling it from device manager.

See image below to device I cannot connect to.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1152284)